# Azure Blob Storage - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage

I'm getting this error message

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Code

```
from os import getenv
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"))
```

Comment: Hi,@Nurdin Could you please explain more in detail and provide enough code?

Comment: so far this is only the starting code.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

The above error notice indicates that the **`getenv`** function returns None, indicating that the environment variable you are attempting to access **`(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)`** is not set.

I created a **`.env`** file and set the **`AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING`**="< My Azure storage account connection string>".

Now you can use the below code as a sample to list the blobs:

**Code:**

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

load_dotenv()

connectionstring=os.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connectionstring)
client=blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
r=list(client.list_blob_names())
print(r)
```

The above code loads environment variables from a .env file using the load_dotenv() function from the dotenv package. It then retrieves the value of the **`AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING`** environment variable using the **`os.getenv()`** function and assigns it to the connection string variable.

**Output:**

```
['06-11-2023.html', 'sample7.mp4', 'uploads/06-11-2023.html']
```

[image]